# Page Reload After Exporting Highchart

Tags: javascript

In my project I am using Highchart,for some reason I need to reload the page after exporting the chart,below code I am tried but this does not working

```
menuItems: [{
                textKey: "printChart",
                onclick: function() {
                    this.print()
                    location.reload(true)
                }
            }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does changing the comma after `this.print()` into a semicolon help?

Comment: That also tried, not working